# Processing one or more symfony2 events inside same transaction

Tags: php, symfony, event-handling, propel

I have found a very [good article](http://problematic.io/2012/03/12/putting-your-symfony2-controllers-on-a-diet-part-2/) on how to keep controller simple and how to organize code in different services by using event/listener mechanism from symfony2.

But the issue I have now is following. Let's imagine I have a controller PostController and it has action DeleteAction. This action will fire event *post_deleted* and there is some other service that should send a private message to the user, whose post has been deleted.

We have now tho distinct actions, that both require access to database and both should succeeded or none of them. **The question is, how do I get Symfony2 to pass same connection+transaction to those two services? Should I put connection object in event self, or there is some other mechanism to keep transaction/connection global across during request handling?**

BTW, I am using Propel.